# Unable to load Vertex Shader from .cso file (DirectX, c++)

Tags: c++, file, directx, shader

I am trying to load a vertex shader from .cso file that I compiled earlier.

The code that I am using to do it is:

```
char* bytes = { 0 };
size_t fSize = readFileBytes("vsTex.cso", bytes);

hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader((void*)bytes, fSize, NULL, &TexVertexShader);
if (hr != S_OK){
    MessageBox(NULL, "FAIL", "ERROR", NULL);
}
```

readFileBytes:

```
  long readFileBytes(const char *name, char* bytes)
    {
        FILE *fl; 
        fopen_s(&fl, name, "r");
        fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
        long len = ftell(fl);
        bytes = (char*)malloc(len);
        fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(bytes, 1, len, fl);
        fclose(fl);
        return len;
    }
```

d3d11Device is a pointer to an ID3D11Device. I had been using D3D11CompileFromFile() to create my vertex shaders witout any errors so there isnt anything wrong with the shader itself as far as I know.

Im not sure if I'm just reading the file incorrectly or if there is something else I have to do to it before giving the function the bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just few things I noticed could cause some problems.

```
long readFileBytes(const char *name, char* bytes)

long readFileBytes(const char *name, char*& bytes) //pass in bytes by reference

fopen_s(&fl, name, "r");

fopen_s(&fl, name, "rb"); //open file in binary mode
```

Finally don't forget to free bytes after you created the shader.

```
free(bytes);
```

Comment: Passing in bytes by reference fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to also use the"rb" option.

Comment: You might find the "ReadData.h" helper in the [DirectX Tool KIt tutorials](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20custom%20shaders&referringTitle=Getting%20Started) useful.

Comment: Wow, that took me a second, but I recognized Walbourn from somewhere.  Your work is wonderful Chuck!